# Mobile game p2p port-forwarding

Tags: c, networking, network-programming

I am trying to create a mobile P2P game with network library written in c (enet/libuv).
I have read in some forum that there is risk of blocked port by the router and I need to do something called port-forwarding.
Most of the topic related are for console games and I'm trying to do mobile game, which theoretically should be the same.

Sorry for my noob question but,  will it be a big issue for my game and how can I fix this problem (without using any third-party help) ?

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Port forwarding is a router feature. Pretty much like nothing to do with either of the tags.

Comment: Yes, but is there something that can be done to prevent users to manually do it ?

Comment: If your user is a "server", no. Nothing can be done. Servers behind a router/firewall have to be configured properly by the server administrator, otherwise it will be a security hole.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this matter: can UPnP be useful? Crystal that this open security matters...